# Configurar a criação de banco de dados em outra pasta

Tags: mysql

É possível mudar a pasta de origem do banco de dados do mysql?

Queria mudar a pasta de origem dele

Comment: Veja lá com os brothers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory

Comment: Eu uso windows, esse forum não ajudou muito não

Answer (score 4):

Sim, você pode parar o serviço e alterar o caminho no arquivo de configuração do `mysql`.

Se for **Windows**, o arquivo é `my.ini`, e fica na pasta de dados do aplicativo, geralmente em "C:\ProgramData\MySQL".

Se for **Linux**, o arquivo é `mysqld.cnf`, e fica geralmente em "/etc/mysql".

Use seu editor preferido e altere a pasta em "datadir=", depois reinicie o serviço.

Comment: Amigão, comigo não deu certo

Comment: Estou alterando o datadir para uma nova pasta, o serviço não inicia

Comment: mas além de alterar você copiou ou restaurou os bancos de dados na nova pasta?